# Wann benutzt man "wie" und wann "als" bei Komparativsätzen?

Tags: comparison

Ich glaubte immer, dass wenn man zwei ungleiche Dinge vergleicht, dann benutzt man "als", um das Verhältnis zwischen ihnen auszudrücken

> Der Tee hier schmeckt besser **als** der Kaffee

und wenn die Dinge auf irgendeine Art gleich sind, dann benutzt man "wie"

> Diese Stadt is genauso groß **wie** die andere

Trotzdem hat man einen Text von mir korregiert, und ich verstehe nicht, warum im folgenden Satz "wie" benutzt wird, weil es mir scheint, dass es einen Vergleich gibt

> Am dritten Tag weiß man vielleicht ***doppelt*** so viel **wie** am zweiten Tag.

Könnte jemand das mir erklären?  Danke im Voraus!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es handelt sich um eine grammatische Regel, nicht eine semantische. Wenn die Phrase eine ist, die für Vergleiche verwendet wird, die etwas gleichsetzen, dann wird "wie" verwendet, auch dann, wenn durch ein Adverb die Gleichsetzung (semantisch) wieder aufgehoben wird. Wenn die Phrase eine ist, die für Vergleiche verwendet wird, die etwas unterscheiden, dann wird "als" verwendet.

Da es heißt "so viel wie" (Gleichsetzung), muss es auch heißen "doppelt so viel wie", "halb so viel wie", "fast so viel wie", "nicht so viel wie", usw.

Comment: Danke! ... aber... eine Gleichsetzung ist auch ein Vergleich (d.h. es ist ein Art Vergleich)... Gibt es eine noch genauere Definition / Erklärung?

Comment: @SylvainGadenne deshalb schrieb ich "Vergleiche, die etwas unterscheiden".

Answer (score 5):

Grammatisch ist die Sache klar: entweder *so* + **Positiv** + *wie* oder **Komparativ** + *als*.

> (doppelt, genau, nur) so **viel** wie …
>
> (kaum, noch, viel) **mehr** als …

Weniger relevant, aber vielleicht auch hilfreich: Mathematisch ist die Sache auch klar. Wenn wir mit W<sub>n</sub> das Wissen an Tag n bezeichnen:

> Am dritten Tag weiß man mehr als am zweiten Tag. (W<sub>3</sub> > W<sub>2</sub>)
>
> Am dritten Tag weiß man doppelt so viel wie am zweiten Tag. (W<sub>3</sub> = 2 W<sub>2</sub>)

Comment: Danke David, dein rechnerisches Abbild finde ich interessant! Könnte ich sagen: Wenn der Satz einen Gleichheit anbietet, benutzen wir "wie". Sonst, wenn der Satz nur eine Ungleichung anbietet, verwenden wir "als"?

Comment: Hmm, mir kommt vor, das wäre *anders dargestellt als* es sich tatsächlich verhält, denn "anders wie" wäre trotz fehlendem Komparativ *anders als* es die Grammatik vorschreibt.

Comment: @bakunin Macht das die Regel schlecht? Diese bezieht sich eigentlich nur auf Adjektive. So gesehen ist schon das Paar *viel, mehr* eine Ausnahme. *Anders als* muß man eben lernen. (Diachron steckt ein Komparativ darin.)